# Getting wordpress to work with the same wp-config.php on wamp localhost and live server

Tags: wordpress, wamp

To facilitate my localhost -> live server migrations, I would like my local Wordpress site (powered by wamp) to work with the exact same wp-config.php file than the one I have online:

```
//Define new directory path
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);

 //Define new directory URL
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
```

So far this is not working, so I have to use this other configuration:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', 'C:\wamp64\www\domain.dev\content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://localhost/domain.dev/content' );
```

What should I do to be able to use the first configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `php` `$_SERVER` array to get the host `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and compare if it is the dev or the live environment.

So, your `wp-config.php` file will looks something like this:

```
$cur_env = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if($cur_env == 'localhost'){ //Or could be '127.0.0.1' - Or whatever your wamp base url is set.
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', 'C:\wamp64\www\domain.dev\content' );
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://localhost/domain.dev/content' );
}else{
    define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
    define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
}
```